# Jest mock not covering the code as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to cover the following function with the Jest unit test.

```
export const submitCampaignForm = (
  formData: IFormContextValues,
  mutate: (formData: IFormContextValues, setCamapignId: any) => void,
  setCamapignId: (val: string) => void,
): void => {
  mutate(formData, {
    onSuccess: (data: ICampaignResponse) => {
      if (data.id) {
        setCamapignId(data.id);
      }
    },
  });
};


it('should call the submit handler', () => {
    const mutateSpy = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      onSuccess: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation((data: ICampaignResponse) => data.id),
    }));
    const updateSpy = jest.fn();
    submitCampaignForm(request, mutateSpy, updateSpy);
    expect(mutateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

to be honest, I'm not sure about whether `mutateSpy` is the right way to mock that function. The test is passing but it's not covering the below lines, what change is required to cover these lines?

```
onSuccess: (data: ICampaignResponse) => {
    if (data.id) {
        setCamapignId(data.id);
    }
 },
```

Comment: Why would it cover those lines? `mutate`'s mock implementation ignores its second parameter entirely, certainly not calling the `onSuccess` prop on it.

Comment: I want to cover those lines, How do I change my mock to accomplish it ? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Thinking about what the actual implementation must be doing, and what I said above about what your test double _doesn't_ do, do you have any ideas?